# How to generate a Rule Compliance report with Helix QaC that includes the line of code where a violation occurred?

Tags: c++, misra, helix

I need to generate a report that includes the line of code where each violation occurred.
I analyzed the JSON files generated by Helix, but I couldn't find any trace of this information, and I couldn't find it in the Helix project properties either.

Comment: I don't know QaC but is there perhaps a "source code with annotations" option spitting out a modified source file? I find that the easiest and most self-documenting way to create such reports.